# "Смириться с чем-л." versus "примириться с чем-л."?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, предлоги

Я помню давнюю передачу по Всесоюзному ещё радио: один из этих глаголов *смириться / примириться" нельзя употреблять с предлогом "с".

Забыла, какой именно, а словари (Большой толковый и Словарь управления) разрешают всё...

> **смириться**
>       с чем и перед чем.
>       **1.** с чем (привыкнув, примириться с чем-л.). Он слишком полюбил море... чтобы смириться со спокойной сухопутной жизнью (Первенцев).
>   ...Не могу смириться с грубостью, невоспитанностью или
>   самоуверенностью (Изюмский).
>       **2.** перед чем (покориться сим обстоятельств). Смириться перед судьбой. Он стыдился именно того, что он, Раскольников, должен
>   смириться и покориться пред «бессмыслицей» какого-то приговора
>   (Достоевский).

Comment: Ну и после изменения вопроса исказился его смысл: люди стали отвечать, какой глагол предпочтительнее и вообще толковать их значение, а меня интересовал только предлог; не надо было вмешиваться в текст профессионального редактора. 8-(

Comment: Простите, не хотел ничего плохого. Просто русское несуществующее слово больно странно смотрелось. Как Вы теперь сделали, тоже неплохо, хотя я не вижу, в чём разница по смыслу. Ещё раз простите!

Comment: А я по иользованию версуса вопрос задала...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно до 40-х годов 20 века глагол смириться употребляли только с предлогами *перед* и *до*. Словарь Ушакова не давал примеров "смириться с кем/чем", а толковал глагол как "стать смирным". Начиная с 50-х, писатели и публицисты начинают широко применять новый оборот с предлогом *с*.
Однако и раньше были такие примеры. Из Славянского Евангелия от Матфея, 5-24 :

> остáви тý дáръ твóй предъ олтарéмъ и шéдъ ***прéжде смири́ся съ брáтомъ тво­и́мъ***, и тогдá при­­шéдъ при­­неси́ дáръ твóй.

Нацкорпус :

> В.А. Шомпулев. Записки старого помещика (1897-1908)
>   Я уже совсем ***смирился с мыслью*** пробыть в Петербурге еще несколько дней...

Очевидно, что подобная практика зависит от того значения, которое придавалось/придается слову "смириться". Помириться с кем (см. Слав. Еванг.); смириться духом, то есть полностью успокоиться перед лицом непреодолимых сил (прежний, слегка устаревающий смысл); привыкнуть к некоторому/временному неудобству (обычное современное значение глагола "смириться").

Answer (score 1):

Оба слова широко употребляются с этим предлогом. Слово "примириться" сложнее употребить *без предлога* "с", если речь идёт не о примирении людей между собой ("они примирились" - самодостаточное выражение). Например, если сказать "Он примирился", фраза в большинстве случаев окажется незаконченной - нужно говорить "с чем" (хотя бы добавить "с этим"), даже если предшествующий контекст даёт понимание, с чем этот "он" мог бы примириться. В такой же ситуации "Он смирился" (если перед этим "его" успокаивали) может оказаться достаточным. Вероятно, различие связано с "избирательностью" примирения: человек может (при)мириться (пойти на компромисс) с одним, оставаясь в бешенстве по поводу другого, в то время как "смирился" несёт оттенок душевного успокоения.

Comment: Саш, это лирика. А мне бы физику, т. е. штамп "Уплочено".

Answer (score 1):

Если бы надо было выбирать, то я бы выбрал *примириться*. То есть именно его будто бы нельзя употреблять с предлогом "с". Якобы нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо, друг! Ты настоящий товарищ и брат. Да только вопрос был зачем-то переделан, и получилось, будто я спрашиваю, какой из глаголов предпочтительнее, в то время как акцент на предлоге!

Comment: Да и мой ответ тоже был переделан. Чёрт знает что... Похоже, здесь в модераторы рвутся не самые грамотные, а наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Примириться «с судьбой неизбежною» можно, т.е. по необходимости и с возможным ущербом принять. *Смиряться* — не от *смирный* (смирный: не шалит), а от *смирения*. К смирению как определённому этапу идут намеренно, добровольно, имея ясное убеждение. Смиряться — и поступок, и этап.

Смириться, в определённой степени, — примирится с миром. Смириться с миром — масло масляное.